# Проверка принадлежности числа множеству

Tags: c#

Есть ли специальные операторы в c# для определения принадлежности числа множеству?
Аналог в паскале: 2 in [1..4], возвращает true в данном случае.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, можно написать метод или даже метод-расширение:

```
public static class RangeHelper
{
    public static bool IsInRange(this int x, int start, int end) => x >= start && x <= end;
}
```

Использовать так:

```
if (2.IsInRange(1, 4))
{
    ...
}
```

[image: Скриншот]

Answer (score 3):

В C# есть тип, представляющий собой множество. Для вашего случая аналогом будет `HashSet<int>`. Проверка вхождения тривиальна:

```
var x = new HashSet<int>() { 2, 3, 4 };
Console.WriteLine(x.Contains(2)); // выдаёт True
```

А вот таких удобных литералов множеств, как в Паскале, в C# нету, ближайшим аналогом `[2..4]` является

```
new HashSet<int>(Enumerable.Range(start: 2, count: 3))
```

Специальной поддержки множеств на уровне синтаксиса языка в C# на текущий момент нет.